# How to loop through all elements of a form jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops

I was just wondering what the best way of looping through all the child elements of a form would be?
My form contains both input and select elements.

At the moment I have:

```
success: function(data) {
                $.each(data.details, function(datakey, datavalue) {
                    $('#new_user_form > input').each(function(key, value) {
                        if($(this).attr('id') == datakey) {
                            $(this).val(datavalue);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```

This only loops through the input elements of the form though and I want to include the select elements too:

I have tried:

```
$('#new_user_form > input, #new_user_form > select').each(function(key, value) {
```

but this doesn't work. Does anyone know why this would be happening?
Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/G8tjU/ You should show the form's HTML.

Comment: We need to see the HTML.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

From the jQuery [:input selector page](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/):

> Because :input is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :input cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :input to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":input").

This is the best choice.

```
$('#new_user_form *').filter(':input').each(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: The logic is good the but the initial selector is wrong. You're filtering the form element. To use the filter function you'd need to do something like `#new_user_form *` in order to then filter only the input elements.

Comment: @scoota269 Oops, I forgot the asterisk. My bad!

Comment: Will this work with non input tag elements? Say like `<select>...` and `<textarea>`?

Comment: @Felipe yes, those are still considered under the scope of an `:input`

Comment: Many different options failed but this a very good choice!!! It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

pure JavaScript is not that difficult:

```
for(var i=0; i < form.elements.length; i++){
    var e = form.elements[i];
    console.log(e.name+"="+e.value);
}
```

Note: because form.elements is a object for-in loop does not work as expected.

Answer found [here (by Chris Pietschmann)](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2006/06/01/JavaScript-Loop-through-all-elements-in-a-form), documented [here (W3S)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_form.asp).

Answer (score 21):

```
$('#new_user_form').find('input').each(function(){
   //your code here
});
```

Comment: This does actually work.  If you want to get selects and textareas as well: $('#new_user_form').find('input, textarea, select').each(function(){
   //your code here
});

Answer (score 13):

As taken from the #jquery Freenode IRC channel:

```
$.each($(form).serializeArray(), function(_, field) { /* use field.name, field.value */ });
```

Thanks to @Cork on the channel.

Comment: This is a perfect solution if you have a listener for all forms. This is my case: `$('body').on('submit','form',function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $.each($(this).serializeArray(),function(counter,object) { console.log(object) }); });` Thanks!

Comment: The first parameter of the callback is the index so it should be: `$.each($(form).serializeArray(), function(index, field) {});`
Still Upvoting :)

Answer (score 8):

I'm using:

```
$($('form').prop('elements')).each(function(){
    console.info(this)
});
```

It Seems ugly, but to me it is still the better way to get all the elements with `jQuery`.

Answer (score 4):

What happens, if you do this way:-

```
$('#new_user_form input, #new_user_form select').each(function(key, value) {
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/5PktA/)**

Answer (score 4):

I have found this simple jquery snippet, to be handy for choosing just the type of selectors I want to work with:

---

```
$("select, input").each(function(){
     // do some stuff with the element
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#new_user_form :input')` should be your way forward. Note the omission of the `>` selector. A valid HTML form wouldn't allow for a input tag being a direct child of a form tag.

Comment: An `input` tag can't be a direct child of a `form` tag?

Comment: @aioobe Technically the <input> spec requires that the direct ancestor be an element that accepts phrasing content. The <form> spec specifies that a direct descendant be of type flow content. In other words, they need one of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content#Flow_content between.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea about that.

Comment: @scoota269 Hmm..  I wonder if that was a categorization mistake.  Mozilla's form examples clearly show inputs as direct descendants of forms..  And input is also a flow element..

Comment: @scoota269 Just saw that Label also has the same restriction that input does.  It looks like phrasing content is a subset of flow content.. with a few extra elements that can only contain phrasing content..

Answer (score 0):

> Do one of the two jQuery serializers inside your form submit to get all inputs having a submitted value.

```
var criteria = $(this).find('input,select').filter(function () {
    return ((!!this.value) && (!!this.name));
}).serializeArray();

var formData = JSON.stringify(criteria);
```

> serializeArray() will produce an array of names and values
>
> 0: {name: "OwnLast", value: "Bird"}
>   1: {name: "OwnFirst", value: "Bob"}
>   2: {name: "OutBldg[]", value: "PDG"}
>   3: {name: "OutBldg[]", value: "PDA"}

```
var criteria = $(this).find('input,select').filter(function () {
    return ((!!this.value) && (!!this.name));
}).serialize();
```

> serialize() creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation
>
> "OwnLast=Bird&OwnFirst=Bob&OutBldg%5B%5D=PDG&OutBldg%5B%5D=PDA"

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through all the fields, you have to also specify type of a field or it will ignore select and textarea and others,

```
$('#formID').find('input,textarea,select').each(function() {
      //Do your stuff here
    });
```

enjoy ;)